# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.simonvt.menudrawer.R$attr working with android 5.0 but exception occurs in android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, apk, noclassdeffounderror, android-4.4-kitkat

I am getting following error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19669): Process: abc.com.abc, PID: 19669
E/AndroidRuntime(19669): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.simonvt.menudrawer.R$attr
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.<init>(MenuDrawer.java:542)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.<init>(MenuDrawer.java:538)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.<init>(MenuDrawer.java:531)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.DraggableDrawer.<init>(DraggableDrawer.java:159)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.OverlayDrawer.<init>(OverlayDrawer.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.createMenuDrawer(MenuDrawer.java:485)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.attach(MenuDrawer.java:456)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at abc.com.abc.BaseActivity.openMenuDrawer(BaseActivity.java:760)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at abc.com.abc.activity.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
E/AndroidRuntime(19669):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.com.abc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    debugCompile project(path: ':pqr', configuration: 'debug')
    releaseCompile project(path: ':pqr', configuration: 'release')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile project(':pageindicator')
    compile 'com.edmodo:rangebar:1.0.0'
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_3_0_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/CleverTapAndroidSDK-v2.2.0-20160718.jar')
    compile 'net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.6'
}
```

As I can see the menudrawer is included explicity, so it doesn't seems to me that this issue is due to sdk version. It works fine on android version 5.0 but error occurs on 4.4.2. Do I need to change some configuration. 
I am new to android.

There is also another `build.gradle` file of library which has different sdk version, as below :

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

I surfed through other links also, but couldn't find any suitable solution

Comment: Don't repost your questions. If you want to add/remove any information, use the 'edit' option in the bottom-left corner of your post.

Comment: I did edited. But the edit was visible when one clicks on edit option. So to hide the config part as per your comment earlier, I had to delete that question. Is there any other option?

Comment: Whoa...then in that case I guess you did right! Just note that deleting your questions can lead to a question ban

Comment: Ok, thanks for informing. Will take care from next time on.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me:

I had set `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle` but did not overrdied the following in my  Application class :

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Doing this override worked for me. 
So you can either use :

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

or you override `attachBaseContext`.